# Edit chrome watch values in chrome debbger

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm new to script debugging in Chrome devtool. Can anyone tell me how to edit chrome watch variable values?

Is there any facility to change script code when debugging in Chrome?

As a example I added to watch list variable:

```
varibleToEditInChrome : "20"
```

I need to change it as follows:

```
varibleToEditInChrome : "30"
```

It's allowed to change but when I edit it, it display as:

```
varibleToEditInChrome : "30" : "30"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an 80% complete feature. Ought to be available within a month.